# moving a drainpipe to put in a free-standing tub on slab construction

Tags: electrical, plumbing, nec

While digging out the concrete to place the drain about 20 inches from its original location, I found a 220-power line, can you run 220-power under the slab 8-12 inches from a drain?

Comment: You can run under a slab I don’t have my book to look it up but I think it is 6” minimum, is it UF or in conduit?

Comment: It's not clear whether you're asking whether there's a minimum separation distance required between an existing cable and your desired new location for a drain pipe, or whether your question is about electrical code: installing a new electric cable or whether an existing cable was legal to have been installed the way it is.